# Crear en Java un CDATA para una llamada en SOAP

Tags: java, xml, java-8, soapui

Tengo el siguiente XML de entrada para un WS de SOAP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:obt="https://xxxxx.sxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
            <obt:ObtenerPendientesGeneralIn>
                <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                        <ns2:mensajeWS xmlns:ns2="https://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet/3.27">
                            <solicitudGetPendientesType>
                                <idSesion>1234</idSesion>
                                <idAplicacion>idAplicacion</idAplicacion>
                                <idSujetoExterno>11111111111</idSujetoExterno>
                            </solicitudGetPendientesType>
                        </ns2:mensajeWS>]]>
            </obt:ObtenerPendientesGeneralIn>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Me gustaría saber cómo construir en Java 8 la estructura de CDATA para que sea enviado al WS. He mirado en foros y no he encontrado nada en concreto.

Nota: **idSesion** será una variable que se recupere de una BBDD, en cambio **idAplicacion** e **idSujetoExterno** tendrán el mismo valor siempre.

Cualquier duda o aclaración, decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.